# Angular 5: Nested JSON not accessible

Tags: json, angular5

I can dump the employee to the console and see the address but unable to push to an array because Angular says it cannot see address.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class StarmarkEmployeeService {

    private addresses: any = [];

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getEmployees() {
        this.http.get('...').subscribe((employee) => {
            console.log(employee); // Works
            this.addresses.push(employee.address); // Doesn't
        });
    }

}
```

The endpoint is an array of the following:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "firstName": "Dejuan",
    "lastName": "Hessel",
    "dob": "1971-12-12T23:21:55.027Z",
    "address": {
        "street": "36948 Daugherty Crescent",
        "city": "North Baileeborough",
        "state": "LA",
        "zip": "57539-9128"
    },
    "phone": "812-157-1264",
    "username": "Dejuan_Hessel39",
    "password": "Adc_4PxXBjC6FTf",
    "email": "Dejuan62@hotmail.com",
    "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/kennyadr/128.jpg",
    "tags": []
}
```

So I modified `get()` to return the HTTP response and will try to obtain address directly.

```
getEmployees() {
    return this.http.get('...', 
        { observe: 'response' })
        .subscribe((resp) => {
        console.log(resp);
    });
}
```

Updated:

```
export class StarmarkDirectoryComponent implements OnInit {

  public addresses: any = [];

  constructor(employeeService: StarmarkEmployeeService) {
    employeeService.getEmployees();
    this.addresses = employeeService.addresses;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

So here is the final implementation:

```
getEmployees() {
    this.http.get<Employee[]>('...')
        .pipe(
            map(employees => {
                const directory = [];
                employees.forEach(employee => {
                    directory.push({
                        firstName: employee.firstName,
                        lastName: employee.lastName,
                        phone: employee.phone,
                        email: employee.email,
                        city: employee.address.city,
                        avatar: employee.avatar
                    });
                });
                return directory;
            }),
            toArray()
        )
        .subscribe(employees => {
            console.log(employees);
        });
}
```

Comment: could it be that its a JSON string?

Comment: When I execute  console.log(employee) it is a JavaScript object and the address key may be expanded to reveal it's key value pairs

Comment: could there be hidden chars around the keys?

Comment: Additionally, PHPStorm IDE complains that address key doesn't exist either

Comment: The following doesn't work either: `this.addresses.push(employee['address']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are treating the service response like it returns a single object and not an array. This is why it is really important to use the types in TypeScript as if the response was typed it would have helped you resolve this.

You rather need to do this:

```
this.http.get<Employee[]>(...).subscribe(employees => {
    employees.forEach(employee => {
        this.addresses.push(employee.address);
    });
});
```

**Update**

Based on your comment below, you'll want to make use of the `map(...)` operator of observables.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; //<-- Need to import observable map operator

import { Employee, Address } from './starmark-employee.model';

@Injectable()
export class StarmarkEmployeeService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getEmployees(): Observable<Address[]> {
        return this.http.get<Employee[]>('http://challenge-dev.starmarkcloud.com/users')
            .map(employees => {
                // You can map your response from an Employee[] to
                // whatever you want. In this case it is mapping to
                // an Address[]. Point is, you do whatever processing
                // on the Employee[] and return the modified response
                return employees.map(employee => employee.address);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated OP. Okay, creating an Interface works and I am able to aggregate addresses. There is one remaining part left. How do I return 'addresses` to the component. I think I need to use a promise or async in the component class?

Comment: @MichaelNiño Is your `getEmployees(...)` method supposed to return the addresses?

Comment: Yes, once I am able to return addresses then I can modify to return the rest. Basically, I will be returning first & last name, email, phone and the city  (in address).

Answer (score -1):

Had to access the response directly. Not sure why Angular5 cannot parse nested JSON but this will work.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Employee} from './employee';

@Injectable()
export class StarmarkEmployeeService {

    private addresses: any = [];

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

   getEmployees() {
        return this.http.get(
        'http://challenge-dev.starmarkcloud.com/users',{
            observe: 'response'
        })
        .subscribe((resp) => {
        for (let b = 0; b < (<any>resp.body).length; b++) {
           console.log(resp.body[b].address);
        }
    });
}

}
```